# PLS-00201 Identifier must be declared

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

This has got to be something really easy to fix, but for some reason I can't get it to work. I keep getting the error

```
PLS-00201: identifier 'ART' must be declared
```

My code is the following:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE question1(givenType IN VARCHAR, output OUT CHAR,output1 OUT CHAR)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT TITLE into output FROM CLASS where TYPE=givenType;
SELECT INSTRUCTOR into output1 FROM CLASS where TYPE=givenType;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The title of any classes with that type is: '|| output|| 'The instructor that taught each class is: ' || output1);
EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No data found');
END;
```

I think the problem may be that when the user inputs "Art" the program takes it in as "ART" and since my table type is "Art" not "ART" then that's why I get the error. I just can't seem to know how to fix it to work. Any help guys?

Sorry guys I fell asleep last night here is the full error that I'm getting

```
Connecting to the database CS425 Spring 2015.
ORA-06550: line 6, column 16:
PLS-00201: identifier 'ART' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 6, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
Process exited.
Disconnecting from the database CS425 Spring 2015.
```

Comment: There's nothing particularly wrong with that code; it doesn't have any references to any identifier called `ART`. Your error is in the calling code, not your procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> PLS-00201: identifier 'ART' must be declared
>
> I think the problem may be that when the user inputs "Art" the program takes it in as "ART" and since my table type is "Art" not "ART" then that's why I get the error.

It has nothing to do with the UPPER/LOWER case. The query is parsed as:

`SELECT TITLE into output FROM CLASS where TYPE=ART;`

If type is varchar type, then you must pass the value as a string, i.e. you must **enclose it within single-quotation marks**. Else, Oracle interprets it to be an **identifier**. So, it should be:

`SELECT TITLE into output FROM CLASS where TYPE='ART';`

For example,

```
SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SQL> DECLARE
  2    o_dept NUMBER;
  3  BEGIN
  4    SELECT DEPTNO INTO o_dept FROM EMP WHERE ENAME=SCOTT;
  5    dbms_output.put_line(o_dept);
  6  END;
  7  /
  SELECT DEPTNO INTO o_dept FROM EMP WHERE ENAME=SCOTT;
                                                 *
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-06550: line 4, column 50:
PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "SCOTT": invalid identifier
ORA-06550: line 4, column 3:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored


SQL> DECLARE
  2    o_dept NUMBER;
  3  BEGIN
  4    SELECT DEPTNO INTO o_dept FROM EMP WHERE ENAME='SCOTT';
  5    dbms_output.put_line(o_dept);
  6  END;
  7  /
20

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

And, it is not a good idea to use reserved keywords as object names. TYPE is a reserved keyword.

Comment: `givenType IN VARCHAR` is an input parameter of proc, and it would be a bind variable to query(implicitly) ... Like.. `TYPE = :givenType`

Comment: OP has not shown how is he calling the procedure. How is he passing the value. The query is certainly not using bind variable as shown in the code.

Comment: `PLS--**` Error means a `PL/SQL` compilation error, so perhaps, the procedure is okay. Hence the caller `PL/SQL` has the error like what you mean.

Comment: Agreed, updated my answer. Had it been what I initially thought, it would throw incorrect identifier error. OP's case is a compilation error, which is not in the current code but in the calling code.

Comment: Okay so I figured out that when the user inputs the type their looking for, since I made it take in a VARCHAR they have to put it in with the apostrophes around whatever they're typing in. I also switched my code around because it will be printing out more than 1 row where as this current code doesn't allow me to. However I'm having problems with that as it doesn't print out anything whatsoever

Comment: @tonyisapony, So I was right about enclosing the value within single quotation marks.

Comment: @LalitKumarB 
yeah you were definitely correct. I also managed to fix my code and now everything prints out thanks so much for your help, I feel so stupid for not realizing that.